# Why some services are called "AWS XXX" and the others "Amazon XXX"

Tags: amazon-web-services, naming-conventions

Some Amazon Web Services are called "AWS XXX" (for example, "AWS Lambda") and others are called "Amazon XXX" (for example, "Amazon RedShift").

Why? Are there any differences?

Comment: Probably you should ask Amazon :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The pattern is that **utility services** are prefixed with AWS, while **standalone services** are prefixed by "Amazon".

Examples of *standalone services*:

- Amazon S3
- Amazon EC2
- Amazon Redshift

Services prefixed with AWS *typically use other services*, for example:

- **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**, **AWS OpsWorks** and **AWS CloudFormation** launch other services
- **AWS Lambda** is triggered by other services
- **AWS Data Pipeline** moves data between other services
- **AWS CloudFormation** launches other services

Mind you, this doesn't apply to everything. For example, **Amazon EBS** can only be used with Amazon EC2, yet it has an "Amazon" prefix.

The [AWS documentation page](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/) is a great reference for determining the official name of a service.

Comment: Interesting,"Amazon API Gateway" is triggered by and triggers other services... wonder why it's different

Comment: What does `utility services` mean ? It doesn't explain what WS stands for in AWS acronym.

Comment: @azbarcea **AWS = Amazon Web Services**. By 'utility services', I refer to services that serve other services. For example, AWS Lambda cannot really be used on its own, it is normally used to support other services.

Comment: This doesn't explain what 'Web Service' is. 'Web Service' is not Utility Service, otherwise it would be Amazon Utility Service :-D

Answer (score 12):

*I originally answered on [AWS products and services naming nomenclature starting with 'Amazon' vs 'AWS'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221189/1381529). I consider this answer needs to be mentioned here as well*.

Context: [Web Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), initially designed as a replacement for [Remote Procedure Call (RPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) was a revolutionary idea during the [Internet Boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-com_bubble) based mainly on XML. Amazon's philosophy was to manage all the [ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) and Customer request using IT instead of traditional paper based processes. The same approach was then applied from **books** to **compute** resources (that's how S3 and EC2 products came to be).

Any service designed to be used by the customer mainly through an API (or Web Service - today it will be [called **API first product**](https://swagger.io/resources/articles/adopting-an-api-first-approach/) ) it is part AWS collection of services, and when the service is seen as a **traditional product** (like replacement of a service that you would install on your desktop or use it from Cloud, mainly through an UI) is part of Amazon collection of services. Today we can see exceptions to this rule. Initially this was the thought of Jeff Bezos. To understand more about his philosophy, read: [The Secret of Amazon success internal APIs](https://apievangelist.com/2012/01/12/the-secret-to-amazons-success-internal-apis/):

> Think about what Bezos was asking! Every team within Amazon had to interact using **Web Services**.
>
> **Anyone who doesn’t do this will be fired.  Thank you; have a nice day!**

*Update*: In a nutshell, if the service is meant to be used (consumed) through an API it will be an *Amazon **Web Service*** (short: **AWS**), otherwise it will be an Amazon product.

*Update*: Based on a comment from AWS employee, there was never an **official** memo that stipulates: 'Anyone who doesn’t do this will be fired' (see comment). The main point is the guideline of using Amazon Web Service (APIs) instead of products.

Comment: This is a late but better and more accurate answer!

Comment: This was never part of any memo of official mandate:

* "Anyone who doesn’t do this will be fired. Thank you; have a nice day!" *

It is merely Steve Yegge's embellishment, based on his opinion.  Steve wrote a fun and insightful piece, but it has been quoted out of context and subject to a game of telephone... there was no such mandate from Bezos

Comment: Ok. Let me update the answer with your insight. Thanks! Please let me know of your feedback.