# AWS products and services naming nomenclature starting with 'Amazon' vs 'AWS'

Tags: amazon-web-services, naming-conventions

Just curious to understand if there are any logical reasoning behind in naming AWS products and services. For example, it has been named as `AWS Lambda` and not Amazon Lambda & it is `Amazon S3` and not AWS S3.

If you hover over the **Products** menu in [AWS homepage](https://aws.amazon.com/), you can see list of all products and services at a glance prefixed with both 'Amazon' and 'AWS'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why some services are called "AWS XXX" and the others "Amazon XXX"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125790/why-some-services-are-called-aws-xxx-and-the-others-amazon-xxx)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Managed to find an answer on naming analogy for AWS products and services from another similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125790/why-some-services-are-called-aws-xxx-and-the-others-amazon-xxx). Response provided by a *Senior Technical Trainer* working at Amazon Web Services.

> The pattern is that **utility services** are prefixed with AWS, while
> **standalone services** are prefixed by "Amazon".
>
> Services prefixed with AWS *typically use other services*, for example:
>
> • **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**, **AWS OpsWorks** and **AWS CloudFormation** launch
> other services
>
> • **AWS Lambda** is triggered by other services
>
> • **AWS Data Pipeline** moves data between other services
>
> • **AWS CloudFormation** launches
> other services
>
> The [AWS documentation page](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/) is a great reference for
> determining the official name of a service.

Comment: One should look deeper into the meaning Amazon "Web Services" in relation to APIs ([wikipedia: Web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)). The concept of "utility" is not the reason for AWS - Amazon Web Service (REST vs RESTful vs WS)

Answer (score 9):

As far as I understand, the prefix AWS is used for PaaS ( Platform as a Service) and prefix Amazon is used for IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service). The term AWS(Amazon Web Service) is used whenever it is offered in terms of service/platform, where as Amazon is used whenever a hardware resource/infrastructure is provided.

For example: In the product page of AWS site, in compute category the Amazon **EC2** is IaaS providing compute capacity where as **AWS Elastic BeanStalk** is PaaS which is a platform for deploying web services and web-apps/wesites, likewise **AWS Lambda** is PaaS for server-less computing which lets us run code without provisioning or managing servers. Similarly in Storage category **Amazon S3** is an IaaS which provides storage capabilities where as **AWS Snownball** is a petabyte-scale data transport solution that uses secure appliances to transfer large amounts of data into and out of the AWS cloud,which is kind of PaaS.

Although this is just a logical assumption, as we never really know about how Amazon has named it's products and services. So please forgive if there are difference of opinions regarding this.

Comment: To an extent, your answer seems to be logically related. One instance where this is contradicting is with `Messaging` category.  Messaging services appears to be a layer above _Infrastructure_, but those are prefixed with 'Amazon' rather than 'AWS' - Amazon SQS, Amazon SES, Amazon SNS, Amazon Pinpoint.

Comment: Aamzon SQS was one of the  first offering from Amazon in cloud domain, may be at that point of time they may not have defined any nomenclature rules. Thereafter they may have continue to use Amazon for all their messaging services for uniformity.

Comment: Very valid reasoning and points. For example, _Storage_ category has services with mix of both prefixes 'Amazon' and 'AWS'. One might also argue that [AWS Snowmobile](https://aws.amazon.com/snowmobile) is not really a service as such that could be consumed as an API or from a browser, but rather an "exabyte-scale" data transfer service used to move extremely large amounts of data from on-premise to AWS by a 45-foot long ruggedized shipping container, pulled by a physical semi-trailer truck.

Comment: Also, it looks like service prefixed with `Amazon` seems to be proprietary to AWS cloud.

Answer (score 0):

In one of AWS Meetups it was told that Amazon itself uses few of its cloud services and these are named with 'Amazon' prefix.

I am not sure how much of this is true..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This would be better as a comment than as an answer. Once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment. Please see [answer] in the meantime.

Answer (score -2):

**Web Service** definition ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)):

> A web service (WS) is either:
>
> - a service offered by an electronic device to another electronic device, communicating with each other via the Internet, or
> - a server (n.e. an Operating System Service) running on a computer device, listening for requests at a particular port over a network, serving web documents (HTML, JSON, XML, images).

Context: [Web Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), initially designed as a replacement for [Remote Procedure Call (RPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) was a revolutionary idea during the [Internet Boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-com_bubble) based mainly on XML. Amazon's philosophy was to manage all the [ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) and Customer request using IT (Web Services) instead of traditional paper based processes (or RPC or not automated tools). The same approach was then applied from **books** to **compute** resources (that's how S3 and EC2 products came to be).

Any service designed to be used by the customer mainly through an API (or Web Service - today it will be [called **API first product**](https://swagger.io/resources/articles/adopting-an-api-first-approach/) ) it is part AWS collection of services, and when the service is seen as a **traditional product** (like replacement of a service that you would install on your desktop or use it from Cloud, mainly through an UI) is part of Amazon collection of services. Today we can see exceptions to this rule. Initially this was the thought of Jeff Bezos. To understand more about his philosophy, read: [The Secret of Amazon success internal APIs](https://apievangelist.com/2012/01/12/the-secret-to-amazons-success-internal-apis/):

> Think about what Bezos was asking! Every team within Amazon had to interact using **Web Services**.
>
> **Anyone who doesn’t do this will be fired.  Thank you; have a nice day!**